# Dropdown-menu disappears when I click a form inside it

Tags: html, jquery, css, ruby-on-rails, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown for Login in a Ruby on Rails project. However, when I click the the forms inside they do not respond.

If I put a z-index on the class "wrapper-dropdown-3" the form responds and the cursor appears before the entire menu quickly disappears.

I read that the stopPropagation() method might work for my problem but so far I've had no luck... Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is my code:

```js
const initDropDown = () => {

  function DropDown(el) {
    this.dd = el;
    this.placeholder = this.dd.children('span');
    this.content = this.dd.find('.dropdown');
    this.initEvents();
  }
  DropDown.prototype = {
    initEvents : function() {
      var obj = this;

      obj.dd.on('click', function(event){
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
      });
    }
  }

  var dd = new DropDown( $('#dd') );

}

export { initDropDown }
```

```css
.header {
  background-color: #7FA269;  /*dark green*/
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
  height: 85px;
  padding: 0px 30px 0px 0px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  border: 1px solid rgba(93, 96, 99, 0.5);
}

.login-avatar {
  border: 1px solid rgba(47, 79, 79, 0.6);
  font-size: 18px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  height: 28px;
  width: 28px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: aliceblue;
  margin-right: 10px
}

.header-menu {
  margin-top: 30px;
  color: darkslategrey;
  font-family: 'Karla';
  font-size: 22px;
/*  text-shadow: 1px 1px 15px darkslategrey;*/
}

.header-menu > li {
  display: inline;
  margin-right: 60px;
}

.header-menu > li:last-of-type {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.dropdown:hover .features-menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: rgb(198, 255, 179);
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding-top: 60px;

  position: absolute;      /* Add these */
  top: -25px;
  left: -30px;

  z-index: 1;
}

.features-menu li {
  list-style: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #FFF;

  padding: 0 40px 10px 20px;
  margin: 10px;

}

.features-menu li:last-of-type {
  border-bottom: none;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown li {
  position: relative;
  color: lightslategrey;
}

.dropdown > span {
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;  /* This is important! */
  cursor: pointer;
}

.features-menu {                    /* Add this as a new rule */
  display: none;
}

.logo {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  height: 83px;
  box-shadow: 0 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);

}

.logo img {
 width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <%= link_to root_path do %>
  <div class="logo">
    <%= image_tag "logo.jpg" %> <!-- change to svg?  -->
  </div>
  <% end %>
  <ul class='header-menu'>
   <div id="dd" class="wrapper-dropdown-3" tabindex="1">
    <% if user_signed_in? %>
    <div class="login-avatar">ら</div>
    <span><%= link_to current_user.username, user_profile_path %></span>
    <% else %>
    <span>Login</span>
    <ul class="dropdown">
     <%= form_for(resource, as: "login", url: session_path(resource_name), html: { id: "login-form" }, remote: true) do |f| %>
     <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :username, class: "text-small-uppercase" %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :username, autofocus: true, autocomplete: "username", class: "text-body" %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :password, class: "text-small-uppercase" %><br />
      <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "current-password", class: "text-body" %>
    </div>


    <div class="actions">
      <%= f.submit "Log in" %>
    </div>

    <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
</div>
</header>
```

Comment: Are you missing a closing </ul> in your view?

Comment: And Your HTML doesn't seems to fit your CSS. You toggle an active class on click that does nothing. You don't have an .active in your CSS. Something is messed up. I would clean the code to make the problem more visible.